# True, false, don't care

Tags: c#, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

I would like to ask about some proper practices for a validation logic.
Any suggestions for valid an input that can be required, not required or don't care.

Case 1: a text field is required.

```
bool required = true;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty("123") != required)
{
   //Error
}
```

Case 2: a text field is not required.

```
bool required = false;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty("123") != required)
{
   //Error
}
```

Case 3: a text field is optional

What i want to achieve is to use one general function to do the validation.

```
//this flag will change based on different input fields
bool required = true; 
if(required != null && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) != required))
{
  //Error
}
```

I've thought about null but I'm not sure if this is the only way to do it.
Thanks All!

Comment: Its unclear to me what you are asking

Comment: aren't you looking for if(validate && !string.IsNullOrEmpty()) - this would ensure if validate is false it does not throw an error else if it is true it would check if nullor empty and then throw the error?

Comment: Don't care would be don't validate

Comment: If you need a boolean with three states, use `bool?` If that isn't what you want, you need to do some work on your question. It is **incredibly** unclear.

Comment: sorry all. I've updated my question. Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
bool? mandatory = null;  // true, false or null for "I don't care"
if(mandatory.HasValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == mandatory.Value)
{
   //Error
}
```

Comment: If you downvoted my now-removed answer, I recommend looking at the [state of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52286216/1) at the point when I answered it, vs when you came to the question. Anyway, based on the question in its current state, it seems that your answer is likely correct, so +1.